# Android for loop not counting properly

Tags: java, android, xml, timer

So I have 3 timers. For the first one I want only to appear once, because it's something like get ready timer.

For the second and third I want to appear as many times as user wants. Before timers start user must select number of times by pressing on + or - buttons which then set value of a TextView.

That's done with this code:

```
int counter = 0;

       homeScreenPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dodajInterval();
                    homeScreenMinus.setEnabled(counter > 0);
                }
            });

            homeScreenMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    oduzmiInterval();
                    homeScreenMinus.setEnabled(counter > 0);
                }
            });


        }

        private void oduzmiInterval() {
            counter--;
            brojIntervala.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }

        private void dodajInterval() {
            counter++;
            brojIntervala.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }
```

And here's the code for timers:

```
 public void homeScreenStart(View view) {
        linearniLayoutSetup.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        CountDownTimer firstCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarTimerDelay.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                countDownTimerTrci();

                karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
                textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_trci));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void countDownTimerTrci() {

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
            CountDownTimer secondCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                    karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
                    imageViewTimerSlika.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_niski_intenzitet);
                    textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_hodaj));
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
                    CountDownTimer thirdCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliNiskogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                            countDownTimerTrci();
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it's a method which is called when button is pressed and I wan't first timer to appear only once and that's why I didn't include it in foor loop.

First timer shows only once and that works, but other two timers keep repeating until I close the app.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: In onFinish from the third timer you are calling the method countDownTimerTrci again, creating a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,replace your countDownTimerTrci method with mine

public void countDownTimerTrci() {

```
    if(counter>0) {
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_trci));
        CountDownTimer secondCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliVisokogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                karticaTimera.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
                imageViewTimerSlika.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_timer_niski_intenzitet);
                textViewTimerTrciHodajBlaBla.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.timer_hodaj));
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.kartica_hodaj));
                CountDownTimer thirdCountDown = new CountDownTimer(seekBarIntervaliNiskogIntenziteta.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        counter--;
                        textViewTimerVrijeme.setText("00:00");
                        countDownTimerTrci();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a God! Thank you!

Comment: As it is keep on going recursively,i just replaced that.So be careful with recursive calling of methods and for futher use check this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/ check this link it might help you